# Backbone.js source read-through

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm reading through the Backbone.js source and am somewhat confused by these lines (L230-238, v0.5.3)

```
unset : function(attr, options) {
  if (!(attr in this.attributes)) return this;
  options || (options = {});
  var value = this.attributes[attr]; // ?: value appears to be unused (?)

  // Run validation.
  var validObj = {};
  validObj[attr] = void 0; //void 0 is equivalent to undefined
  if (!options.silent && this.validate && !this._performValidation(validObj, options)) return false;
```

Am I crazy or does the last line run a validation against a hash object with a single undefined attribute?

It seems like the validation is intended to run on an instance of the Model object with the attribute-to-be-unset removed.

[Current source on github with lines highlighted](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L230-238)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're correct in your assessment of what it does, but that's the intended functionality.

when you call unset, you can only tell it to unset one attribute at a time: `model.unset("myAttr")`

when unsetting, validation is called to make sure the model will be put into a valid state. if the attribute being set to undefined will cause the model to be invalid, the unset fails. if it is valid for the attribute to be undefined, the attribute is removed from the model.

the reason it passes a "hash object with a single undefined attribute" is that all objects in javascript as "hash objects" - key value pairs, or associative arrays. it doesn't matter how you get an object, it is an associative array.

an object with one empty attribute named after the model's attribute that is being unset, is created in lines 236-237. this is so that monkeying with the object passed into the validate method won't change the state of the model itself.

hope that helps explain things.

Comment: That does help, but I don't see how a copy of the model's attribute is added in lines 236-237.  Is `void 0` doing more than returning `undefined`?  I can see that the object being checked is `this`, and that is passed to `_performValidation` as `this`.  Perhaps it'd be easier for me to understand if I knew where the .validate(attrs) method comes from (line 397) in `_performValidation`

Comment: oops! you're right... it is just an undefined. mistake on my part. fixed my answer. the `validate(attrs)` method is a method that you write in your model. if you don't provide it, it's not called. if you do provide it, it gets called: `MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ validate: function(attrs){ ... }  });`

Comment: ah okay, that makes sense.  So it's up to the `MyModel.validate(attr)` method to take `attr` -- an object hash with an undefined value, and check whether that key/value pair would invalidate `this`?

Comment: right - it runs the `validate` method with the attributes that have "changed" (been deleted in this case), so you can validate the model is ok. see the example in the docs http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-validate

Comment: Okay, this makes sense now.  I can see how validate works with `unset` for validations like `attr.key1 != invalid_value`.  It seems like some validations, such as `(attr.key1 + attr.key2).length != 2` would pass when they shouldn't--though it's admittedly a convoluted case (unless I'm missing something again).

Comment: you'd have to do something like `this.get("attr1") + this.get("attr2")` to make that scenario work. the attrs that are passed into the validate method are only the ones that are changing, but you still have access to the full model as `this`.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for answering the question so thoroughly!